# SSH - Remote into Server behind JumpBox

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I'm trying to work out if you can do this. I'm wanting to SSH into the end machine (server). I want to be able to authenticate into the jump box station from the management terminal with key authentication which is fine and done. But my issue is coming when jumping from jump-box into the server with key authentication.

[image: Diagram]

Is there a way to ssh into the server from management terminal (via jump box) without the keys being stored for Server on the jump box and only on the management terminal?

Both the JumpBox and Server will be running Ubuntu and Management Terminal can be windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can tunnel the connection with `-W`. This will effectively use port forwarding on the Jump box to transparently create a direct tunnel and is the preferred method.

Use the `-A` switch to for ssh-agent forwarding. This is generally frowned upon since your keys are available (but NOT stored) to anyone on the jump box for the duration of the session.

You can find many more examples and info here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts